# Convert String to javax.jms.Message

Tags: java, string, jms

I'm working on a JMS application. I'm facing a scenario where I need to convert an XML in to javax.jms.Message object. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `createTextMessage` on `javax.jms.Session`, e.g.

```
String xml = ...
Session session = ...
Message message = session.createTextMessage(xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

For pure JMS API, see skaffman's answer. If you happen to have Spring in the mix, it makes sending JMS messages really simple. Just call [JmsTemplate.convertAndSend()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#convertAndSend%28java.lang.Object%29). Pass it any String, and it will automatically wrap it up into a TextMessage. Pretty much any JMS interaction is [much easier with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html).

Answer (score 0):

It actually might depend on your JMS provider. We used IBM MQ as messaging provider, and I remember that we did it like this:

```
com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage textMsg = new com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage();
textMsg.setText(yourText);
```

But I'm not sure if it's the correct way.

Comment: In IBM MQ 9.3.0 this does not work. Fails with 
"java.lang.AssertionError: Do not call messages default constructor, use javax.jms.Session methods instead"